# Estimates and estimators strict definition

Tags: regression, model

Let's look at a simple regression model:

Y = $\hat{\beta0}$ +   $\hat{\beta1}$Xi + $\hat{e}$

Estimator's definition is that it's a rule for arriving at an estimate, in this example it would be a rule how the hatted terms on the model are calculated.

But when talking about estimates, is it correct to say the values for the $\hat{\beta1}$  etc. are estimates, and in addition correct to say that the actual values of the regression line ie. $\hat{\beta1}$Xi are also estimates. (So the coefficient values and actual variable estimate values are BOTH called estimates).

Comment: sorry, what's the question?

Comment: @Chuse is it correct to say that the b1 coefficient is an estimate, but also that the b1x1 "real value" is an estimate. Or does the term apply only to one of those?

Comment: Estimates are the values obtained by specific formulas/rules called estimators. Arithmetic mean is both estimator (as formula) and estimate (as number). _Another_ line of definitions that might interfere here is the distinction parameter vs statistic-as-estimate-of-parameter.

Answer (score 0):

An estimator is a function of the sample, i.e., it is a random variable. The corresponding estimate is the value of a particular outcome of that random variable.

In this case $\hat\beta_1$ and $\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1x_i$ (which I assume that you are actually interested in) are estimators of the coefficent for $x$, and the value of $y$ at $x_i$, respectively. The actual values of these estimators obtained from your observations are the estimates. So, both of your given examples are estimates.